# Javascript selecting option from a select dropdown, using a href

Tags: javascript, html, href, html-select

Im working on a CMS website that creates form elements on the fly according to id and values.
I need to select certain information out of these forms using a link.

For radio options and checkbox options I use this code:
`<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('RAL1').checked=true">1001</a>`
Which works fine.
RAL1 is the id of radio I want to check.
With the select the id needs to be follwed by the options and this is where Im having problems because it needs to select a value out of an ID.

The code the form creates is

```
<select id="Zinc_plated_field" class="inputboxattrib" name="Zinc_plated12">
  <option value="no">no</option>
  <option value="yes">yes (+€871.08)</option>
</select>
```

I've tried just about everything but no luck. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just about every browser supports the following statement to **get** the selected value (`"no"` or `"yes"`):

```
document.getElementById('Zinc_plated_field').value
```

For very old browsers you would have to use:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('Zinc_plated_field');
sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

---

If you want to **set** the selected value, there are several ways to do it:

```
document.getElementById('Zinc_plated_field').value = 'yes';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('Zinc_plated_field').options[1].selected = true;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('Zinc_plated_field').selectedIndex = 1;
```

The two latter use the index of the option you want to set (one specifies which index is selected by setting the `selectedIndex` property of the `<select>` element, while the other sets the `selected` attribute of the `<option>` element to `true`.)

I can't say which is most cross-browser compatible off-hand, but if the first one doesn't work, just try the other two.

Comment: AFAICS, he wants to set the value, not get it.

Comment: The first setter example (`.value = 'yes'`) works in all browsers and is blazing fast. However if a matching `value` attribute is not present on one the `<option>` list it will fail **in IE** (all versions), even if there is a matching `text` attribute present.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Firefox & Safari:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('Zinc_plated_field').value = 'yes'">yes</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('Zinc_plated_field').value = 'no'">no</a>
```